# How to properly call functions with struct param?

Tags: c, xcode

I am writing a program that asks users to add, edit, and print employee information. I can't seem to properly calculate the Amount paid and taxes paid for each employee. I am trying to do it using functions that take struct as a param and return a value. It will properly calculate the Amount paid and taxes paid for the first employee entered, but then it will pass some of that info from the first employee to the following employees. I am not sure if I am properly passing the calcpay and calctax functions properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5

struct database{
   char name[SIZE][20];
   float hours[SIZE];
   float rate[SIZE];
};

void loademployee(struct database* employee){

   for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
      printf("Enter name: ");
      scanf("%s", employee -> name[i]);

      printf("\nEnter hours worked: ");
      scanf("%f", &employee -> hours[i]);

      printf("\nEnter hourly rate: ");
      scanf("%f", &employee -> rate[i]);
   }

   puts("\n");
}

float calcpay(struct database employee){

   if(*employee.hours <= 40){
      return *employee.hours * *employee.rate;
   }
   else{
      return (40 * *employee.rate)+((*employee.hours - 40)*1.5 * *employee.rate);
   }

}

float calctax(struct database employee){

   if(*employee.hours <= 40){
      return *employee.hours * *employee.rate * 0.2;
   }
   else{
      return ((40 * *employee.rate)+((*employee.hours - 40)*1.5 * *employee.rate)) * 0.2;
   }

}

void printemployee(struct database *employee){

   for(int b=0; b<SIZE; b++){
      printf("Pay to: %s\n", employee->name[b]);

      printf("Hours worked: %.2f\n", employee->hours[b]);

      printf("Hourly rate: %.2f\n", employee->rate[b]);

      printf("Amount paid: %.2f\n", calcpay(employee[b]));

      printf("Taxes paid: %.2f\n", calctax(employee[b]));

      printf("Net pay: %.2f\n", calcpay(employee[b]) - calctax(employee[b]));
   }
}


int main(void){

   struct database employee;

   int input, userchoice;

   for(int x=0; x<50; x++){

      printf("1: Add Employee Data ");
      printf("\n2: Update Employee Data ");
      printf("\n3: Print Single Employee ");
      printf("\n4: Print All Employees");
      printf("\n5: Exit ");
      printf("\nSelect an Option: ");
      scanf("%d", &input);

      switch(input){
         case 1:

            loademployee(&employee);
            continue;

         case 2:

            printf("Select Employee to Update: \n");
            for(int r=0; r<SIZE; r++){

               printf("%d.%s\n", r, employee.name[r]);
            }
            scanf("%d", &userchoice);

            for(int y=0; y<SIZE; y++){

               if(y==userchoice){

                  printf("Enter name: ");
                  scanf("%s", employee.name[y]);

                  printf("\nEnter hours worked: ");
                  scanf("%f", &employee.hours[y]);

                  printf("\nEnter hourly rate: ");
                  scanf("%f", &employee.rate[y]);
               }
               continue;
            }

         case 3:

            for(int s=0; s<SIZE; s++){
               for(int j=0; j<SIZE; j++){
                  printf("%d.%s\n", j, employee.name[j]);
               }

               printf("Select an Employee to print: ");
               scanf("%d", &userchoice);

               for(int z=0; z<SIZE; z++){

                  if(userchoice == z){

                     printf("Pay to: %s\n", employee.name[z]);

                     printf("Hours worked: %f\n", employee.hours[z]);

                     printf("Hourly rate: %f\n", employee.rate[z]);

                     printf("Amount paid: %.2f\n", calcpay(employee));

                     printf("Taxes paid: %.2f\n", calctax(employee));

                     printf("Net pay: %.2f\n", calcpay(employee)-        calctax(employee));

                     return main();

                  }
               }
            }


         case 4:

            printemployee(&employee);

            return main();

         case 5:

            exit(1);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new "employee" variable every time a user inputs 3 or 4. Your case statements need to be terminated with break statements instead of continue or return statements.

"return main()" is a function call to main(). This causes a the current employee database to be pushed onto the stack. Insert the line printf("%p\n", &employee); before the main for loop and you will see that a new variable is created at a different memory location every time the 3rd and 4th options are chosen.

Instead of continue and return statements, you should be using a break statement.

Also, you need to initialize the employee database to be safe:

```
struct database{
char name[SIZE][20] = "";
float hours[SIZE] = {0};
float rate[SIZE] = {0};
};
```